# Prevent Sql injection in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

In my project I have one method which is taking **serviceTags** as a string parameter input in nhibernate dynamic query and  replacing that with ''. Now its  already parameterized but still its a threat to sql injection. So my question is to get this kind of functionality without threat what should I do? User input's type/length check is already in my mind and I don't think that will solve the whole threat.

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> GetCollectionStatus(string serviceTags)
 { using (var session = m_SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
           foreach (var resultParts in session.CreateSQLQuery(string.Format("select servicetag , " +
                                                                             "DiagnosticStatus from AssetOverview where servicetag IN ('{0}')", 
                                                                             serviceTags.Replace(",", "','"))).List())
            {
                collectionStatus.Add(((object[])(resultParts))[0].ToString(), ((object[])(resultParts))[1].ToString());
            }
        }
        return collectionStatus;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for considering SQL injection even when using an ORM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection, that is to use NHibernate to format your strings, simply do this:-

```
var q = session.CreateSQLQuery(
   "select servicetag, DiagnosticStatus from AssetOverview 
       where servicetag IN (:list)")
   .SetParameterList("list", serviceTags)
   .List();
```

NHibernate will escape the single quotes for you.

**edit** I would do the following as well as I can see that the `serviceTags` is a comma delimited list...

```
   .SetParameterList("list", serviceTags.split(','))
```

Mind you this might give problems if you have leading/trailing spaces or blanks!

Comment: @Rippo but serviceTags.Replace(",", "','")) is required,so will you please modify it?

Comment: updated to reflect that service tags is a comma delimeted input NOT a `List<string>`

Comment: @Rippo Thanks. After changing my code I'll  revert back later.